# what is wrong with my dijkstra algorithm for undirecting graph with equal weight in perl. it doesn't stop iterating

Tags: arrays, perl, graph, hash, dijkstra

I have an weighted graph for protein nodes. I was writing a Perl program to find the shortest path for a given node using Dijkstra's Algorithm. Each protein (vertex) has equal weight. My program doesn't stop iterating and doesn't give me any output. I don't know what is causing the problem.

My idea is to get the name of a protein node from the user and start searching the shortest path by using the given protein as a root node.

```
%graph = (
  'A' => {'B' => 1, 'C' => 5},
  'B' => {'C' => 4, 'D' => 2},
  'C' => {'A' => 1, 'B' => 3},
  'D' => {'C' => 2, 'B' => 3}
);

sub dijkstra {
    print "Enter a node\n";
    my $root= <>;
    my $infinity = "inf";
    my %graph= %graph;
    my %dist;
    my %prev;
    ############################ the algorithm ####
    # first, set all distances to infinity
    foreach $n (keys %graph) { $dist{$n} = $infinity; $prev{$n}=$n; }
    # .. except the source
    $dist{$root} = 0;
    # loop while we have unsolved nodes
    # sort unsolved by distance from root
    foreach my $n1 (sort keys %graph) {
        foreach my $n2 (keys %{$graph{$n1}}) {
            if (($dist{$n2} eq $infinity) ||
                ($dist{$n2} > ($dist{$n1} + $graph{$n1}{$n2}) )) {
                $dist{$n2} = $dist{$n} + $graph{$n1}{$n2};
                $prev{$n2} = $n1;
            }
        }
    }
    ##### print the solutions ######
    my $path;
    foreach $n(keys %graph) {
        my $t = $n;
        $path = $t;
        while ($t ne $root) { $t = $prev{$t}; $path = "$t -> " . $path; }
        print "$n\t$dist{$n}\t$path\n";
    }
}
dijkstra();
```

Comment: The [code sample](http://sscce.org/) is incomplete without sample data (the value of the global `%graph`).

Answer (score 7):

When you read input using `<>`, it includes the trailing newline character. As a result, it isn't equal to any of the keys in `%graph` (which presumably don't have newline characters). The quick fix is to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the root.

```
...
my $root = <>;
chomp $root;
```

The complete fix is to check that `$root` is a valid vertex and output an error if not. Note that you shouldn't handle user input and application logic in the same function. [Separate concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) to reduce [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29).

Also, [globals are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). Package variables aren't so bad if that's what you're doing, but `%group` should be passed to `dijkstra` (as a [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)) so the implementation isn't that closely tied to the graph. Passing the graph as a parameter tightens up the code.

Note that you don't need to define your own infinity. Perl has `inf` (and `-inf`).

```
sub dijkstra {
    my ($graph, $root) = @_;
    my (%dist, %prev);

    ############################ the algorithm ####
    # first, set all distances to infinity
    foreach $n (keys %{$graph}) { $dist{$n} = inf; $prev{$n}=$n; }
    # .. except the source
    $dist{$root} = 0;

    # loop while we have unsolved nodes
    # sort unsolved by distance from root
    foreach my $n1 (sort keys %{$graph}) {
        foreach my $n2 (keys %{$graph->{$n1}}) {
            if (($dist{$n2} eq inf) ||
                ($dist{$n2} > ($dist{$n1} + $graph->{$n1}{$n2}) )) {
                $dist{$n2} = $dist{$n} + $graph->{$n1}{$n2};
                $prev{$n2} = $n1;
            }
        }
    }
    return (\%prev, \%dist);
}

sub getNode {
    my $graph = shift;
    print "Enter a node\n";
    my $root= <>;
    chomp $root;
    if (! exists $graph->{$root}) {
        die("'$root' isn't a valid node.\n");
    }
    return $root;
}

sub printPaths {
    my ($graph, $prev, $dist) = @_;
    my $path;

    foreach $n (keys %{$graph}) {
        my $t = $n;
        $path = $t;
        while ($t ne $root) {
            $t = $prev->{$t}; $path = "$t -> " . $path;
        }
        print "$n\t$dist->{$n}\t$path\n";
    }
}

$graph = {
  'A' => {'B' => 1, 'C' => 5},
  'B' => {'C' => 4, 'D' => 2},
  'C' => {'A' => 1, 'B' => 3},
  'D' => {'C' => 2, 'B' => 3}
};
$root = getNode($graph);
#($prev, $dist) = dijkstra(\%graph, $root);
#printPaths($graph, $prev, $dist);
# or, for obfuscation:
printPaths($graph, dijkstra($graph, $root));
```

To debug something like this, you can use scaffolding (print debugging messages at various points in the code; [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm) is useful for this). Better yet, learn to use an [interactive debugger](http://debugger.perl.org/).

Comment: thanks dude, but i still have a problem when i try to reference my graph, normally what i've done is, I just reference my graph that i've already implemented it by reading from the file and put it in a hash.

Comment: @Michael.Z: SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. If you have a different question, post it as such once you've searched to make sure it's not a duplicate. You can link back to this question (or answer) in your new question, should you wish to provide context. Make sure any [code samples](http://sscce.org/) in your new question are minimized: complete and concise.

Comment: Read the FAQs, if you haven't already, to familiarize yourself with how SO works. It's not what you think.